# ASP.NET ASCX Use of Instance Variable

Tags: asp.net, instance-variables, ascx

Let's say I have an ASCX user control that requires access to the current user's full name.  An ASPX page contains this line at the top

```
<%@ Register src="top.ascx" tagprefix="custom" tagname="top" %>
```

and this line in the body:

```
<custom:top runat="server" />
```

The ASPX file knows the user ID of the current user and could determine his full name.  So how can I use the code run by the ASPX file to provide its information to the ASCX file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`Page` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx) of the user control and cast it to the instance of your page. Then, call the method of your page class to get the user name.

To make this work in a dynamically compiled project, you have to do a little more work to have the control recognize the data type of the dynamically compiled page. [Here is a short tutorial on how to do](http://aspalliance.com/1461_Page_and_User_Control_Communication.all).

Or, as [Brandon outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176990/107625), do the opposite and let your page tell your user control the information.

Comment: The answer in your first paragraph worked best for me.  I thought I had already tried this.  It worked great and was trivial to implement whereas Brandon's solution, although really cool, would have required more work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Declare a property on the UserControl and have the parent page set it.

On your usercontrol:

```
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

On the aspx page either set it in the code behind

```
YourUserControl.FullName = FullName
```

or through markup

```
<custom:top runat="server" FullName="<%= SomeProperty %>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, Brandon!  This could definitely prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might be mistaken about how the page lifecycle works and how you can expose data across your controls. For example, lets say you have this code in your ASPX:

```
  public override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
       string userName = "Bob";
  }
```

In your ASPX file, you can reference the control and set a property on it to pass the data along:

```
  <custom:top ID="someControl" runat="server" />
```

You expose a property in your `top` control like so:

```
  public string UserName { get; set; }
```

You could then add this code to your `OnLoad` method:

```
  someControl.UserName = userName;
```

Then your control will have access to that data. Alternatively, you can stick things in the Request cache if you dont have a direct line to the control:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Items["key"] = userName;
```

And then pull the data from your control via the same fashion:

```
  string fromCache = HttpContext.Current.Items["key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go about this in several ways. I typically use a session variable, since the user will be bound to the session.

In the ASPX (or when the user logs in):

```
Session["UserFullName"] = GetFullName(); //Code to get full name here
```

In the ASMX:

```
this.FullName = Session["UserFullName"]; //TODO: Check for null values
```